# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given

Filename: sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php

this is my db config in database.php

```
$db['db3'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'd_trial',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

this is my query on model

```
function getTrial(){
    $db3 = $this->load->database('db3', TRUE);
    return $db3->query("select * from dbo.t_dpt");
}
```

this is my function on controller

```
public function get()
{
    $data['bu'] = $this->m_ppit->getDataBU()->result();
    $this->load->view('v_data', $data);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlsrv\_query() expects parameter 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836603/sqlsrv-query-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: no, I've set the config above. I'm trying to call the query from the model to the controller. but still, error like that

Comment: `getDataBU()` != `getTrial()` - are you referencing the correct functions?

Comment: Where's the code calling `sqlsrv_query()`? Check the [sqlsrv_query documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php). A common mistake is for people to invoke `sqlsrv_query($sqlQuery, $connection)` instead of `sqlsrv_query($connection, $sqlQuery)` but your error message sounds like you could be invoking `sqlsrv_query($someBooleanValue, $whateverWhatever)` instead.